# Collecting Outputs from C Code with Different Parameters in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I have this piece of code that produces some output with printf statements on the console. I want to somehow collect the data into a .txt file when I run this code multiple times with different variables, for example if my program is called "produce", I want to get the outputs of:

```
./produce 0
./produce 1
./produce 2
```

and so on. Any way of automating this? Thanks.

Comment: Write a shell script to run it multiple times. Redirect the output to a specific text file.

Comment: I've never used shell before, can you give me an example?

Comment: check this http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ And the most easy one is just write the command one by one.

Comment: Look at the "Redirection" section in the [Bash manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple shell script for this.

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
echo "Output of produce for $i" >> output.txt
./produce $i >> output.txt
done
```

Put the above code in a file like test.sh. And then run the command `sh test.sh` on the console and you should be seeing the file output.txt getting created with the desired output in it.

Make sure to rename output.txt before running the script everytime.

Comment: Thanks, this did it but I had to change the ./produce i to ./produce $i

Comment: Ya. That was a typo. I'll correct it.Hope it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are nervous of the shell, then just modiify your code to write to a file  which is named using the input parameter.

See [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html) for how to write to a file.

```
FILE *outputFile;
outputFile = fopen(strcat(strcat('output_', argv[1]), '.txt, "wt");  // output_0.txt, output_1.txt, etc
```

Replace all `printf(` with `fprintf(outputFile,` and that's it.